# Issue with fixed header - no horizontal scroll

Tags: css, html

I need to have header visible while user scroll page.
I set header to be fixed position and it stays while scrolling but when I resize browser I don't get horizontal scroll bar so I can't see all items in navigation for example.

```
<body>    
        <header>
            <div id="topHeader">
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
                <nav>
                    ... navigation items ...
                </nav>            
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>    
</body>
```

css

```
#content{margin-top:80px;}
#topHeader{width: 100%; background: #262626; height: 40px;margin:0;}
header
{   
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to get the behaviour of the facebook header

```
<div id="headercontainer" style="position: fixed; width: 100%">
  <div id="actualheader" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

with the following jquery:

```
<SCRIPT>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#actualheader').css('left', -$(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

Haven't tested for compatibility

Comment: This worked very well, and seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in html/css.  Go to [this site](http://www.incrediblemarketing.com/) and shrink the browsesr window way down, the footer is fixed position and you lose the content on the right, but if you use the horizontal scrollbar it moves.  I did this with jquery.  Here is the code I used.  Basically I am moving what is inside the fixed div in relation with the windows scroll location.

```
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#copyright').css({ 'left': (20 - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px' });
    $('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': (20 + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px'});
  }
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#copyright').css({ 'left': (20 - $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px' });
    $('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': (20 + $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px'});
  }
  else {
    $('#copyright').css({ 'left': '20px' });
    $('#click-to-call, #erving').css({ 'right': '20px' });
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width to 100%, which means 100% of the viewport in this case. The element won't expand past that point, meaning no horizontal scrollbar.

You really shouldn't be fixing something to the viewport that doesn't fit inside of it. Consider adding some kind of arrows to pan around the navigation when it gets too large.

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width.  and give older browser a different experience, Or you can write some js to tell the header not to ever get smaller then [number]. This solution should fix it for *Modern Browsers*.

```
header{   
    min-width:960px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: If I add this then only content is scrollable.

Comment: You could set a min width on the body as well.

Comment: That doesn't work. Problem is because my header is positioned fixed. But I didn't find another way to make what I want here.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but this worked for me. I wrote this java function positionContentBelowHeader to increase the margin of the content table so that it shows up directly below the fixed header.

Set your fixed header to have no minimum width and it will squeeze really small when the window is shrunk. Then, call position content function in the body resize event. This way, at least nothing is cut off, and the content slides down to adjust for the taller, compacted fixed header.

In asp.net code behind, I also have to add this to run the position function on page render

```
'Save dynamic employee panel height into property using javascript.
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "positionContentBelowHeader", "positionContentBelowHeader();", True)
```

I place this in the body

> id="objMasterPageBody" onresize="positionContentBelowHeader()";

>

```
           <script type="text/javascript">

               function positionContentBelowHeader() 
               {
                    //Set header height
                    var headerHeight = document.getElementById('<%= TableHeader.ClientID %>').clientHeight;
                    document.getElementById('<%= hidHeaderHeight.ClientID %>').value = headerHeight;            //margin: 0px auto 0px auto; height: 100%;
                    document.getElementById('<%= TableContent.ClientID %>').setAttribute("style", "height: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: " + headerHeight.toString() + "px");

               }

            </script>
```